# "Unexpected CDB Error" in QtCreator -- correct debugger attached

Tags: qt, debugging

My code compiles fine, but when I go to run it I get an "Unexpected CDB Error" in Qt. To my understanding, this has something to do with the debugger. I checked C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64 and cdb.exe is there and properly linked in QtCreator. Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of Qt and what version of Qt Creator?

Comment: Qt 5.10.1 and Qt Creator 4.6

Comment: Try upgrading to Qt Creator 4.8. I sort of remember them chasing CDB issues in some of the earlier Qt Creator versions.